# Storing a class in local storage?

Tags: javascript, authentication, store

Please tell me, I am working with the ual-anchor library for authorization, as well as with ual-plainjs-renderer for rendering a modal authorization window. My problem is to store an instance of the UALJS class in local storage (or somewhere else) so that I can access this class even after a page reload.

Comment: I forgot to write that the instance of this class is a circular structure

Answer (score 1):

You are limited to store string key/value pairs in localstorage. The only option is to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse(obj)`

checkout this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2010948/12165605

Answer (score 0):

Try using localStorage like this--

```
localStorage.setItem("class", JSON.stringify(class));
let class = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("class"))
localStorage.removeItem("class");
```